# why Spring throws HttpMessageNotReadableException with different CAUSES for JSON

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a exception handler controller where I am  catching  HttpMessageNotReadableException as below:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    protected ErrorMessage handleJsonException(final HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    if (ex.getCause() instanceof JsonParseException)
    {
       // some code
    }
    if (ex .getCause() instanceof JsonMappingException)
    {
       // some code
    }
}
```

i got different causes for POST and PUT with malformed json(the first double quotes is missing in JSON text)

```
{firstName":"abc","lastName":"xyz"}
```

POST - JsonParseException

PUT - JsonMappingException

I believe both should have the same cause "**JsonParseException**" as the syntax is wrong.

Can anyone suggest why spring gives different for PUT as "**JsonMappingException**".

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something to resolve this kind a problem, I found this article -> http://www.jayway.com/2013/02/03/improve-your-spring-rest-api-part-iii/
It has a few ideas to workaround, like using "getMostSpecificCause". I'm reading it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
//ex -> HttpMessageNotReadableException

```
    Throwable throwable = ex.getCause();
JsonMappingException jsonMappingException = ((JsonMappingException) throwable);
    // import 'InvalidFormatException' from  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc package
    List<JsonMappingException.Reference> references = ((InvalidFormatException)throwable).getPath();
    for (JsonMappingException.Reference reference : references) {
        if (reference.getFieldName() != null) {
            field += reference.getFieldName() + ".";
        }
    }
    String message = jsonMappingException.getOriginalMessage();
```